# How to make clicking more robust in web testing?

Tags: automated-testing, web-application, oracle-ats

The specific tool I am using is Oracle Openscript, part of the Oracle ATS package. However, their web-based component uses xpath-based object identification, so it has a lot in common with other, more popular tools.

The problem I'm having is that after recording a series of navigation clicks on heavily-styled elements (for example, `<a>` elements styled to look like buttons using jQuery), a simple playback fails to click on them. It turns the correct element pink, which I believe is OpenScript's way of identifying what it's trying to click, but then times out unless I manually click it. Clearly the click event is failing.

I know record and playback is immensely fragile, so I'm trying to build a library of helper functions I can use to build tests in the future. What methods generally do people use to combat fragility of click methods in tools? Surely there's a better way than just trying in a loop until navigation changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this were Selenium, what I would do is first wait for the element to exist before I tried to operate on it (especially if I'm seeing this problem on IE, seems to be a common annoyance with that browser unfortunately)

Rereading your question, I think something like this will solve it. That you can click it manually after the tool loads the page and fails to execute the same click indicates a likely race condition.

I think there is a way to do this with OpenScript, according to [this oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24640_01/E15488_05.pdf), by setting a separate wait for a particular object like the anchor tag.

> Expand the Object Timeout group and set the preferences as follows:
>   Timeout(S): Specifies the maximum number of seconds OpenScript should
>   wait  for an object to appear before considering the object not found.
>   This is the default  timeout when waiting for an object to appear
>   before invoking an action against it.  This is also the default
>   timeout when waiting for an object to appear before  continuing the
>   script.  You can override individual object wait timeouts in
>   waitForPage() or  object.waitFor() by editing their "timeout"
>   properties. Action timeouts  cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 2):

Do a search on this site for 'wait' - does your tool offer that option? Seems you're clicking before the element us fully loaded/ready so you need a command to wait around until it is.

Comment: The tool is waiting for a page load between each step.

Comment: I think what he means is that your tool is might be firing the click too soon after the page loads. Given that the element is heavily stylized with jquery I would agree with his hunch; I've seen it plenty of times myself. Are you able to insert a wait in between the page load and the click to verify if this is the case?